# Images, titles and margins

Tags: graphics, margins, titles

I am writing a report and I need two things: there must be an image in the title page at the top left and I have to add a 5mm left margin to odd pages and a 5mm right margin to even pages, how can i do these things?

for the image I'm trying with

```
\begin{figure}[t]\flushleft
  \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{pic.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

but the following text will go along with the image, and I want it to stay centered vertically and horizontally:

```
{ \huge \bfseries Title}\\[1.5cm]
\textsc{\LARGE Subtitle}\\[1.5cm]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You don't need to use `figure` in order to use `\includegraphics`. For fixed placements of single images like this you should not use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

For your margin requirements, use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry):

```
\usepackage[inner=5mm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
```

This will add a `5mm` inner margin (left for odd-numbered and right for even-numbered) in `twoside` mode.

For your image requirements, consider using the following structure (and avoid `\maketitle`, since it is just easier):

```
\begin{document}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{pic.jpg}

\begin{center}
  {\huge \bfseries Title} \par \bigskip
  \textsc{\LARGE Subtitle}
\end{center}

%...
```

If you want a bigger gap between the title elements, you can use more `\bigskip`s, or you can insert a manual `\vspace{15mm}`.

It is also possible to have the image and the centred title at the same vertical position, if needed. It wasn't that clear from the original post.